# Retrain Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a tensorflow model which I trained using object detection SSD mobile net .
The training is finished now and I exported the model inference for testing .My inquiry is if I want to retrain the model later with new dataset of images, what should i do now at the stage to make the weights permeant in the model so that I can retrain it from that point on .I know there is a freeze script ,do I have to use that ?

Thanks

Ayad

Comment: Have you tried [checkpointing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints)?

Comment: How did you save the model?

Comment: I used export_inference_graph.py to export the training model

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrain it from that point on. Every time you retrain it should be for all objects that you are interested in.

Comment: The SSD model for example comes with prebuilt weight that can be used to do various detections which you can use as starting point to train your own dataset .Im looking for the exact usage ,I want my trained model to be a stating point for new dataset .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood your question.
I have understood you are retraining your model and what to freeze the weights (the CNN part, right?)

1. So create a empty model
2. transfer the weight of the trained model
3. freeze them

   ````py
   pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), 
                               include_top = False, 
                               weights = None)  
   pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights_file)
   for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
       layer.trainable = False```
   ````